# Position setting for marquee text

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a product slider in which the product changes on click of next and previous button.Now i have used marquee tag for auto scroll.But problem is i want marquee with left direction should start from given position.How to do that.

```
<marquee behavior="scroll" scrollamount="4" direction="left"  onmouseover="stop();" onmouseout="start();">
    <div class="scrollable" id="scrollable">
    </div>
</marquee>
```

Comment: Ohmygawd `marquee` tag D: And obtrusive JS, BTW...

Comment: A `marquee` tag? Are you kidding me?

Comment: According to the W3: _"The `<marquee>` element is a non-standard element. HTML5 classifies it as a non-conforming feature. **No, really. don't use it.**"_

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using this ancient tag, you probably should build a slider using jQuery.
If you are still learning you can try one of [these plugins](http://vandelaydesign.com/blog/tools/awesome-jquery-sliders/). I just Googled for "jQuery slider"... there are many many many others out there.

Goodluck!